# How to detect when you should install or upgrade RPMs automatically?

Tags: rpm

I want to write a script that installs or upgrades a set of RPMs without knowing what is already installed on the system.

Is there a way to do this from a script? I did not see any option like upgrade or install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rpm -Uvh
```

handles both, says [the documentation](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/ch-rpm-upgrade.html).

Comment: Or to make it more complete: use install only for kernels.

Comment: @sorin Libraries might work with `-i` as well, if they are crafted with care.

Answer (score 0):

There are [python bindings](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch-rpm-programming-python.html) available.

Or you can simply `rpm -U <packages> --replacepkgs` which will allow the same exact version to be reinstalled.